# how to tell grep to continue to the next

Tags: grep

I have a huge file from which I'm interested to retrieve several values (long numbers). Most of the time the number starts at the end of the line and continues to the beginning of the next line and grep is not able to retrieve it all.

For example, my numbers are in this form: `-1234.1234567` so when I use

```
grep -Eo '-[0-9]{4}.[0-9]{7}'
```

it doesn't return all the values because sometimes the numbers go like this:

```
blah blah blah ....-1234.12

34567 blah blah blah
```

So, is there a way to tell grep to continue looking (if needed) to the next line to retrieve all 7 decimals of the number?

Thanks

Comment: forgot to mention that I have over 1000 files

Comment: Note that . in your RE matches any character, not just a period. Is that what you want? Also, what would you want to happen if a string like hello-1234.1234567 or -1234.12345678 existed in your file (i.e. does your target string need to be delimited by something)? How do you know when 2 numbers separated by a newline should remain 2 separate numbers or be concatenated? Does the same apply to all strings of digits separated by ANY white space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to remove the horizontal whitespace and then preform your grep.

Try: `cat myfile | tr -d [:blank:] | grep -Eo '-[0-9]{4}.[0-9]{7}'`

If you wanted to do this for all the files in a directory you could just use a for loop:

```
for i in *; do cat $i | tr -d [:blank:] | grep -Eo '-[0-9]{4}.[0-9]{7}'; done
```

Comment: Thanks. It didn't work though. Still didn't return the numbers that continue to the next line.

Comment: Fixed it by adding [:blank:] to your tr command. However, is there a way to do that over 1000 files at once? Thanks

Comment: @user3157486 I think you can use grep to search through the files of a directory.  Would that be what you're looking for?

Comment: According to the command you proposed above, it uses cat, and can be done successfully on individual files, but I have over 1000 files and cat doesn't work with *.txt for example. Is there a way to fix that? Thanks

Comment: You could just use a for loop to perform this command on all your files individually

Comment: Note that the above will convert 2 space-separate numeric strings that do not match your pattern into one that does, e.g. a line with `-  12 34.1234 5678` will become `-1234.12345678`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @EdMorton yes that's what I want. The numbers contained in the files are only in this format. I just want to perform this command for 1000 files.

Comment: @user3157486 Edited my answer. Does that work for you?

Comment: @SwankSwashbucklers Yes. worked like a charm. Now I only got a ton of numbers, Is there a way to also print the name of each file from which the numbers are retrieved?

Comment: @user3157486 Just add the command to print the filename to the for loop: 'for i in *; do echo $i; cat $i | tr -d [:blank:] | grep -Eo '-[0-9]{4}.[0-9]{7}'; done'

Comment: @SwankSwashbucklers Excellent. Now the last piece of the puzzle. I'd like the numbers to be printed beside the file name and not on a new line below the file name. Is that possible?

Comment: @user3157486 it's possible but not really relevant to your original question. You should accept an answer on this question and then open a new one, and I'll see if I can find a solution that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you asked for (uses GNU awk for ENDFILE):

```
gawk -v OFS=': ' '
{ rec = rec $0 }
ENDFILE {
    while ( match(rec,/-[[:digit:]]{4}[.][[:digit:]]{7}/) ) {
        print FILENAME, substr(rec,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        rec = substr(rec,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    rec = ""
}
' *
```

For example:

```
$ cat file1
blah blah blah ....-1234.12

34567 blah blah blah

blah blah blah ....-2345.2345

678 blah blah blah

$ cat file2
blah blah blah ....-4321.12

34567 blah blah blah

blah blah blah ....-9876.2345

678 blah blah blah

$ gawk -v OFS=': ' '
{ rec = rec $0 }
ENDFILE {
    while ( match(rec,/-[[:digit:]]{4}[.][[:digit:]]{7}/) ) {
        print FILENAME, substr(rec,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        rec = substr(rec,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    rec = ""
}
' file1 file2
file1: -1234.1234567
file1: -2345.2345678
file2: -4321.1234567
file2: -9876.2345678
```

Try it with some real sample input that includes edge cases like strings that end in 8 digits instead of 7 and let us know of any additional requirements.

If you don't have GNU awk you can do the same with a function doing the match() called when FNR==1 and in END. There's various alternatives too....